# Failed to clone a repository from Bitbucket through PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a repository from BitBucket to my local PC (Windows 10)

I've gone into the repo in BitBucket and copied the link to clone the repo (HTTPS option).

I then go to the folder in my local PC where I want to clone it, open the Powershell command prompt and paste the link.

It seems to load and then prompts me to sign in to my Atlassian account, which I do and then I get the below error:

**fatal: helper error (-1): Cannot access a disposed object.**

I've tried resetting my password in Atlassian but no luck. I know I'm typing in the correct credentials because I've tried many times at this point.

I have downloaded and signed up for Git too, so I don't think there is an issue there. I think the problem is some connection to from my PC to BitBucket through PowerShell.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've attempted this before in another PC and it's worked fine. When it's worked in the past, after typing the git clone command in PowerShell the repository is created locally with no errors, and it never prompted me to insert my credentials.

I've also tried using the SSH key option when copying the link in BitBucket to clone the repo and it says I don't have permission.

SOLVED: The issue was that I was entering the wrong credentials and I needed to set an app password for a new device in BitBucket.

Comment: 1) BB has **not** "HTML option" for clone, only https and SSH 2) "helper error" error message definitely show you the reason of problem - you have locally some credentials helper(s) and **failed helper** ruined all. Use correct command without any bells and whistles

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: The issue was that I was entering the wrong credentials and I needed to set an app password for a new device in BitBucket.

Comment: Could have been a comment!

Comment: what could have?